# Broken file path on iOS device, not on iOS Simulator

Tags: javascript, titanium-mobile

I've built my app with Titanium Appcelerator. I can build and run my app on iOS Simulator for iPad and iPhone. However, when building to my devices, my iPhone build can't find the files. iPad works fine.

I'm checking for the osname, and setting these variables accordingly to true or false, depending on which device they're running. Like I mentioned, the iPhone simulator loads the file perfectly, but on the iPhone it throws up a bad path error, which means my iPhone variable is being set to true, since it's attempting to find it. Is there something I'm overlooking when building to iPhoen? The code looks like this:

```
var ipad = false;
var iphone = false;
var iOSCheck = function(){
if(Titanium.Platform.osname == 'ipad'){
    ipad = true;
    Titanium.include('games/views/ipad/options.js');
} else if(Titanium.Platform.osname == 'iphone'){
    iphone = true;
    Titanium.include('games/views/iphone/options.js');
} 
    if(iphone || ipad){
        Titanium.UI.iPhone.statusBarStyle = Titanium.UI.iPhone.StatusBar.OPAQUE_BLACK;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I've edited the code to show a more specific senario of what I have.

Comment: Try to throw away the build files before you build for device

Comment: Hi Topener, yes. I've cleaned my project countless times and rebuilt. No idea why it's happening. My understanding is that running it in the simulator is actually using symlinks for the files, which is why it may not be error-ing out. But then errors on the device

Comment: add your check on which OS it runs (the code) to your question please

Comment: That's exactly what's in the question above.

Comment: How is the variable ipad/iphone filled. How do you check it? Add that code. If the variables are filled correctly, this should just work.

Comment: I edited the code in the question to show more accurately how I have it in my project.

Comment: Still not the complete code. is the function actually called?

Comment: All of this code is called. When running on the iPad, the file is loaded accordingly. The fact that an error is thrown on the iPhone, saying that the file isn't found, is proof that it's running. Otherwise it would not be attempting to load it. What other code do you need??? this is the entire function.

Comment: Try `    Titanium.include('/games/views/iphone/options.js');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. It turns out that the only reason it wouldn't work was because the folder was named 'iphone'. Perhaps this conflicts with the default iphone folder where the images are? Regardless, I renamed the folder to phone and it works fine now. Very strange.